# Shiro Spring with filterchain definitions equivalent for @RequiresRoles logical.OR

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, shiro

I am trying to enhance my spring-enabled web-app's security using Apache Shiro and am thus configuring filterchain definitions into a spring-configured file.
How do i achieve the equivalent of

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mywebapp")
// @RequiresAuthentication (is this possible ? wish i could do this !)
public class MyWebAppController  {

@RequiresRoles(value={"Role1","Role2","Role3"},logical=Logical.OR)
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() { return .. }
```

and my spring-config file contains this : 
assume that my dispatcherservlet is mapped to /rest/*

```
  <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/rest/secure/windowslogin"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/mywebapp/rest/menu"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/mywebapp/rest/unauthorized"/>
    <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="anon">
                <bean class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AnonymousFilter"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="authc">
       <!-- why is this not invoked ? -->
                <bean class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter">
                </bean>
            </entry>
            <entry key="roles">
                <bean class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter"/>
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /rest/secure/** = anon
            /rest/mywebapp/** = authc, roles[Role1,Role2,Role3]
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the code above i need a logical.OR kind of mapping to the `/rest/mywebapp/**` using the roles mentioned. This is possible via shiro annotations and it works but rather than specifying at every method i would rather handle it here (since i dont think shiro supports class level annotations yet ?) .
Is this possible ?

Also on a side note why is the authc filter not invoked ?
( for now we assume that the windows login can serve as authentication, using shiro only for authorization )

```
home page = meta refresh to /rest/secure/windowslogin/
             if within intranet -> login ...
             else /rest/secure/login ... login page.
```

Is it because the loginurl is different ? How do i circumvent this ? Note that my realm's getAuthorizationInfo is invoked though using the roles[ .. ] part specified in the config file.. but i was assuming that there should be a check to see if the request is 'authc' ? (which probably means that the filter is invoked and SubjectUtils.getSubject() is checked for authentication). Am i missing something in the flow or configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how shiro-security.xml looks like.

```
<bean id="customFilter1" class="com.pkg.RolesAuthorizationFilter">
        <property name="roles" value="ROLE1,ROLE3,ROLE5"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="customFilter2" class="com.pkg.RolesAuthorizationFilter">
        <property name="roles" value="ROLE1,ROLE2,ROLE5,ROLE6"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/login" />
        <property name="successUrl" value="/home" />
        <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized" />    
     <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="authc">
                <bean   class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter" />
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>

<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
             /resources/** = anon
                /login = anon
                /logout = authc             
                /unauthorized = authc
                /someurl/** = customFilter2
                /** = customFilter1
            </value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

And this is RolesAuthorizationFilter class

```
package com.pkg;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.AuthorizationFilter;

public class RolesAuthorizationFilter extends AuthorizationFilter {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()
            .getCanonicalName());

    private String[] roles;

    @Override
    protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws Exception {

        logger.info("= Roles = " + Arrays.toString(roles));

        Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
        boolean allowAccess = false;

        for (String role : roles) {
            if (subject.hasRole(role)) {

                logger.info("Authenticated role " + role);

                allowAccess = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return allowAccess;
    }

    public void setRoles(String[] roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }   
}
```